# Error in RenderPartial in loop asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am trying to render multiple Views using a loop like this

```
@model IEnumerable<RamtaJogi.Web.Razor.Controllers.IMenuRenderer>

@foreach (var item in @Model)
{
    {@Html.RenderPartial(@item.ViewName, @item.ViewData);}
     <br />
}
```

here is my IRenderer

```
public interface IMenuRenderer     
{
    string ViewName { get; }
    object ViewData { get; }
}
```

But it throws an error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

I pass a collection of objects of type IMenuRenderer  to my view.

Any idea what is wrong with my codes. Can someone help here.

Regards

Parminder

Comment: Can you post your implementation of IRenderer/IMenuRenderer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many `@` characters.

You should only use `@`s to enter the `foreach`.
Since `RenderPartial` returns `void`, you cannot print its result with an `@`.
Parameters also never get `@`s.

Change your code to

```
@model IEnumerable<RamtaJogi.Web.Razor.Controllers.IMenuRenderer>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial(item.ViewName, item.ViewData)
     <br />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom helper.I think this will help you. [ASP.NET MVC: Custom Html Helpers in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216736/asp-net-mvc-2-to-mvc-3-custom-html-helpers-in-razor)